# Reloading UIModalViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, reload, modalviewcontroller

I have a super simple presentation for iPad with few modal views. At every View user makes a simple action (like dragging a slider), after that appears UIButton "Next" what presents new modal View above previous. Button in last view connects with first view by a modal segue. So app needs to work in recursive way. But after first time presentation goes (from the second loop starts), all Views presented with all actions done in them. So I want that all app ModalViewControllers reloads to the default state every time user taps button on the last View.

Can I implement this behaviour only set it in -prepareForSegue of UIButton in last ModalViewController or it's a more global issue? If so, how to implement that?

Comment: `ViewWillAppear` will be called on `ViewController` before appearing the model view

Comment: Can you be just a little more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `viewWillAppear` in every `ViewController` will give you an opportunity to reset the view before the view gets to the screen. When you come back to a `ViewController` from another `viewController`, `viewWillAppear` gets called.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear");

   [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 

    //Reset your view (i.e. hide next button etc.)

}
```

Comment: Ok, but answer was actually HOW to reset.